# Site thumbnail not coming in alfresco community

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and when I search for a site in a live search, I don't get the site thumbnail.

Not Found error:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/res/components/images/filetypes/generic-site-48.png

Below is screenshot of a live search with no thumbnail for a sample site.

[image: site ss]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please try by  placing 'generic-site-48.png' file at \tomcat\webapps\share\components\images\filetypes\ and check.
Hope this will work.